# Branding Xamarin application

Tags: c#, xamarin, branding

I am searching a way to brand application for different customers. Android Studio build system, Gradle, offers a mechanism of flavors, which allows replacing resource or code files, depending on selected application version. This allows easily achieve such features as branding application or creating lite and pro versions.

The simplest way (I imagine) I can do the same in Visual Studio with Xamarin is to create different source control branches in the project, but unfortunately this solution is quite hard to maintain: every change must be manually merged with all branches before deployment.

Is there another specific mechanism meant for this task?

Comment: Write your MSBuild extension can simply solve this.

Comment: use define's and create different build configurations which enable these defines